# Prolog: iteration

Tags: lambda, prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

Good evening,
i have a simple problem, and i warn you that i am very new with prolog.
Suppose to have three lists of the same size, each containing only 1s, 0s or -1s.
I want to verify that for all i, of the i-th elements of the three lists, one and only one is nonzero.

This code does it for a fixed i:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

compat1(V1,V2,V3,I) :-
    length(V1,G),
    nth1(I,V1,X),
    nth1(I,V2,Y),
    nth1(I,V3,Z),
    W is X*X+Y*Y+Z*Z,
    W is 1,
    I in 1..G.
```

how can I tell "for ALL I, compat1(V1,V2,V3,I)"?
I tried to define

```
compat2(V1,V2,V3,1) :- compat1(V1,V2,V3,1).
compat2(V1,V2,V3,K) :- compat2(V1,V2,V3,J), compat1(V1,V2,V3,K), K is J+1.
```

so that I could call it with K=maximum value i'm interested in.
But compat2 doesn't work: gives true, then, after ";" runs indefinitely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks: Mixing `library(clpfd)` and `(is)/2` is mostly not a good idea. You can write `X #= Y + 1` in place of `X is Y + 1` with almost the same efficiency (in SWI) but enjoying its increased generality.

The relation you are interested in, relates the i-th elements of three lists. That is, we can write: `maplist(r, Xs, Ys, Zs)` where `r/3` is the relation you are interested in. So we have to define `r(X,Y,Z)`.

What about `abs(X)+abs(Y)+abs(Z) #= 1`?

With [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) you can put it all into a single line:

```
maplist(\X^Y^Z^(abs(X)+abs(Y)+abs(Z) #= 1), Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

Comment: Elegant and simple. Very useful, and thanks for telling me not to use is/2.

Comment: Another question. How do i sum in a list, involving the index? For example, how can i sum over i the expression I*A(I)?

Comment: There is no generally agreed upon way to do this compactily. So the best would be to write it the pedestrian way recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple recursion. The program does only test the input, it cannot be used to generate solutions. If you need that, you have to say which values are allowed in the facts, e.g. by adding `onlyOne(0,0,1). onlyOne(0,0,-1).`, etc.

```
onlyOne(0,0,_).
onlyOne(0,_,0).
onlyOne(_,0,0).
onlyOne([],[],[]).
onlyOne([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3]) :- onlyOne(H1,H2,H3), onlyOne(T1,T2,T3).
```

Edit: Re-reading the question I guess you require that exactly one entry is nonzero, not at most one. In that case you need these rules instead of the facts:

```
onlyOne(0,0,X) :- X \= 0.
onlyOne(0,X,0) :- X \= 0.
onlyOne(X,0,0) :- X \= 0.
```